# AngularJs Capture links and open link within a new jquery tab

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am currently prototyping a new web application and i need to open some links into a new jquery tab

I am looking into AngularJs as we want to keep the site to a one page app

can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: ive got no code yet as im unsure on how to approach this

Comment: Ok so new tabs are browser tabs or tabs inside the page ..??

Comment: tabs within the page

Comment: Please elaborate your question i didn't get you.
You need code for tab like view (why jquery)..?
You need to open a link(url) into new tab ..??

Comment: i have a sidebar with links to otherpages, rather than just do a page reload to that url i want to add a new jquery tab and load the content of that page inside that tab

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/TMN3KNlS4Dv90SvbTQKJ?p=info like that but rather have the tabs defind the clicking of any links adds a new tab with a url for its content